# Valid Java Exception Handling - is it really required in all cases?

Tags: java

I'm reading through the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html). This example is what I'm questioning:

> The first kind of exception is the checked exception. These are
>   exceptional conditions that a well-written application should
>   anticipate and recover from. For example, suppose an application
>   prompts a user for an input file name, then opens the file by passing
>   the name to the constructor for java.io.FileReader. Normally, the user
>   provides the name of an existing, readable file, so the construction
>   of the FileReader object succeeds, and the execution of the
>   application proceeds normally. But sometimes the user supplies the
>   name of a nonexistent file, and the constructor throws
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException. A well-written program will catch this
>   exception and notify the user of the mistake, possibly prompting for a
>   corrected file name.

In PHP I would check to see if the file exists prior to accepting it as valid user input with something like:

```
    if (file_exists($file)) {
       //proceed
    } else {
       //throw error to user
    }
```

Am I to understand from reading this that in Java you would just need to "assume" the file provided was valid, and use the exception handler to throw an error instead of just checking to see if it exists?  Or is using an Exception a much cleaner/efficient way of checking to see if the file exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done either way; which makes more sense depends on context--but however it's implemented, checked exceptions must either be handled, or declared to be thrown. That may change what makes the most sense.

I tend to check for a file's existence before trying to do anything with it. But exceptions are just that--(generally) intended for *exceptional* circumstances.

For example, my app checks to see if the file exists, and it does. Between then and using the file, something else comes along and deletes it. Now there's an exceptional condition that my code must handle as gracefully as possible.

Comment: The advantage of checking for File.exists() is that then an error is truly exceptional, not just a typo by the user.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to your specific example: The exception handling isn't necessarily (just) a way to validate the user's input; it's an alternative to handling an error return from (what would be, in PHP) an `open` or `read` operation (hidden inside the `FileInputStream`). Think of it as an alternative to the `$err = do_something ($foo)` model. Rather than writing,

```
 $err = do_something ($foo);
 if ($err) {
     complain ($foo, $err);
     return;
 }
 do_something_else;
```

you have the (arguably more readable?)

```
 try {
     foo.doSomething ();
     doSomethingElse ();
 } catch (SomeException e) {
     foo.complain (e);
 }
```

Ideally, your whole operation inside `try {}` is legible at a go, and the `catch` clauses handle all the paranoia in one place.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right - Java best practices would recommend code like this:

```
try {
    FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(file);
    // proceed
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // report error to user
}
```

Though there are some complexities, for example in closing a file which may or may not have been successfully opened.  Java 7 has a special syntax to make that much easier (called [try with resources](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/java-7-try-with-resources-explained.html)).

I'd note that there's a race condition in that PHP code that could result in a successful `file_exists()` call, but a missing call once the file is read.  And of course it may exist but not be readable.